# how to add custom username available and email available methods as rules in kohana

Tags: php, kohana

What is the correct format to add rules to check unique username and email in kohana 3.3

I have tried the followings

```
 array(array($this, 'unique'), array('username', ':value')); // added similar to email also
 array('username',array('unique_username'); // / added similar to email also
 array('username',array('unique_username',array(':value')); // / added similar to email also

public static function unique_username($username)
{
    echo 'running';

    // Check if the username already exists in the database
    return ! DB::select(array(DB::expr('COUNT(username)'), 'total'))
        ->from('users')
        ->where('username', '=', $username)
        ->execute()
        ->get('total');
}
```

I am getting the following error

> Argument 3 passed to Kohana_Validation::rule() must be an array,
>   string given

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you an exact answer because you don't show your class name. For example, if your class was named `Model_User` here's how your would use a static method as a validation callback:

`->rule('username', 'Model_User::unique_username', array(':value'));`

or

`->rule('username', array('Model_User', 'unique_username'), array(':value'));`

Comment: Thanks, i think this rule has to be added on a seperate validation object in the controller and pass it to the save object, if, yes can you please add it to your answer for the benefit of people who checks this thread at a later point for time?

Comment: @logeeks In Kohana you'd save this to the model as demonstrated in the [`Model_Auth_User`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Model_Auth_User#rules)